# Аналог nameof для XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017

Нужно хранить локализованные названия свойств классов в словаре ресурсов. Сейчас делаю это так:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<system:String x:Key="Scale">Шкала</system:String>
```

Но хотелось бы использовать тот факт, что "Scale" является названием свойства класса KingLaw. Свойство, как и сам класс не статическое.
Хранить в качестве ключа словаря объект PropertyInfo, используя XAML у меня не получается. Может быть можно написать пользовательское расширение разметки, которое позволит работать с названиями свойств? Хотелось бы сделать аналог следующего, только при помощи XAML:

```
        ResourceDictionary properties = new ResourceDictionary()
        {
            { nameof(KingLaw.Scale), "Шкала" }
        };
```

Comment: Пользовательские расширения разметки нельзя использовать в качестве ключей в xaml, но вообще расширение такое можно написать, конечно

Comment: А чем вас c#-вариант не устраивает?

Comment: Хотел предусмотреть дальнейшую возможность локализации приложения на любой язык. При создании словаря в XAML проще будет изменить язык приложения просто подключив словарь, соответствующий культуре. Хранить же ресурсы в виде хардкода не слишком красивое и гибкое решение.

Comment: А как насчет XAML 2009? Нет ли у него нужных возможностей? Если есть, то может его можно использовать в последней студии?

Comment: Ну, словарь, созданный в коде, подключается не сложнее, чем тот что в xaml. С XAML 2009 лучше не связываться, можно сказать что он не поддерживается на уровне фреймворка

Comment: Вообще в коде можно создавать словарь на основе данных, хранящихся отдельно (в файле в удобном вам формате или в БД), как по мне, это даже более гибкое решение.